# Django: Add entry to junction table after creating an entry (post_save)

Tags: django

I have this table

```
 ----------------
 | project      |
 ----------------
 | project_id   |
 | project_name |
 ----------------

 ------------------
 | project_member |
 ------------------
 | project_id     |
 | user_id        |
 ------------------
```

How do I add a project_member entry (using the current logged in user as user_id) after creating a new project entry?

I can't make it work using post_save.

If it's not possible, what could be a better approach?

Here's my post_save code:

```
 class Project(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

 class ProjectMember(models.Model):
      project_id = models.ForeignKey('Project', db_column='project_id')
      user_id = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model())

 def project_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
      pm = ProjectMember(project_id = instance, user_id = sender)   

 signals.post_save.connect(project_post_save, sender=get_user_model())
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you tried for post_save? Maybe there is something you missed and someone will notice :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the new object, or else use the manager's `create` method. Inside or outside a signal, merely creating a model instance with its constructor does not automatically save it to the database.

Comment: I actually did it. But it didn't work. I tried however that Instead of ProjectMember, I created a new instance of Project(name='test') and it got saved without calling pm.save()

Comment: Looks like your signal is on the wrong model, then. Your current configuration hooks in on *user* save.